# Constant Global object on a Ruby on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

Working with Rails 3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.3, where is the proper place to initialize a Global constant object such that it is only initialized once when the rails server is started.

Right now I am declaring it as instance object as and it is initialized every time the method is called:

```
@object_wanted_to_be_global_const = Gemname::GemnameClass.new 'input'
```

Where is the best place to declare this as a global constant variable?

If declared as a global instead of an instance, how will this affect performance as the variable is accessed on almost every request?

Comment: I'm thinking probably declare it in `application_controlller.rb` but wouldn't it be reinitialized upon each request still?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in an initializer.

And to respect Ruby's convention, capitalize the whole name.

I can't see any performance issue regarding this method.

Comment: Initialize it in `config/initializers/gem_name.rb` as `$GLOBAL_OBJECT = ...`?   As well, will you explain how this will affect performance?

Comment: you don't need the `$`. It won't affect performance, it will just be loaded in memory (as are all your i18n values)

Comment: so `ALL_CAPS_VARIABLE` -> global variable and constant variable? Is this part of the Ruby language or a convention employed by rails?

Comment: Use a constant which will be available everywhere. I never use global variables.

Comment: So in the ruby language constants are available everywhere? (doesn't that make them global variables?)  Or is this a rails convention that any constant defined in the initializer is available everywhere?

Comment: All constants are available everywhere. They are just tied to their context. If you define `FOO = 1` in an initializer, you'd be able to call `FOO` everywhere. If you define a constant in a class, you'll have to prepend the constant name with the clas' name: `CLassName::CONSTANT_NAME`